# Streaming video files in asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, filestream, memorystream

I want to play video in browser using asp.net core

in html I have

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source src="http://localhost:55193/api/VideoPlayer/Download" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and in asp.net core 2

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Download")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
    {
        var path = @"d:\test\somemovie.mp4";
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"d:\test\somemovie.mp4", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 65536, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(path));
    }
```

Does this code play file by streaming( I mean buffer file chunk by chunk and play)?

And if I want to play file from any position which user set the player's progress, How I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the normal `return PhysicalFile` here:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Download()
        {
            return PhysicalFile(@"d:\test\somemovie.mp4", "application/octet-stream");
        }
```

Because it supports range headers which are necessary for streaming and resuming a file download:
[image]

Also `return File`, `FileStreamResult` and `VirtualFileResult` support `partial range requests` too. Even `static files middleware` supports that too.

Comment: are you sure there is accept-ranges in response headers?! I used your code but it didn't have accept-ranges header

Comment: where do you think that image is coming from?

Comment: I don't know where but I think this code `return PhysicalFile(@"d:\test\somemovie.mp4", "application/octet-stream",true);` results in an image like that. Anyway, How can I set the start position of file to download? for example download a file from middle?

Comment: thanks. I got it. there is a header like `{bytes=93028160-}` in the request headers which `PhysicalFile` recognizes where to start.

Answer (score 3):

Something is wrong. My sample doesn't support resume

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Download2")]
    public IActionResult Download2()
    {
        return PhysicalFile(@"d:\test\somemovie.mp4", "application/octet-stream");
    }
```

[image]

and there is no accept-ranges in response headers

[image]

but when I use

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("Download")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
    {
        var path = @"d:\test\somemovie.mp4";
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"d:\test\somemovie.mp4", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 65536, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(path),true); //enableRangeProcessing = true
    }
```

with "enableRangeProcessing" parameter true

[image]

Can you provide more explanation why the case is this?
And which solution I should use? I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
  static MediaStream song = null;
        static byte[] SongArray = null;

song = await client.GetMediaStreamAsync(streamFilter).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        song.CopyTo(ms);
                        SongArray = ms.ToArray();

  long fSize = song.Length, startbyte = 0, endbyte = fSize - 1;
                int statusCode = 200;

                var rangeRequest = Request.Headers["Range"].ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rangeRequest))
                {
                    string[] range = Request.Headers["Range"].ToString().Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
                    startbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);

                    if (range.Length > 2 && range[2] != "")
                    {
                        endbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[2]);
                    }

                    if (startbyte != 0 || endbyte != fSize - 1 || range.Length > 2 && range[2] == "")
                    {
                        statusCode = 206;
                    }
                }

                long desSize = endbyte - startbyte + 1;
                Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
                //  Response.Headers.Add(ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue(String.Format("\"{0}\"", _eTag));
                Response.ContentType = "video/" + streamFilter.Container.GetFileExtension();
                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Accept", Response.ContentType);
                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", desSize.ToString());
                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startbyte, endbyte, fSize));
                return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(SongArray, (int)startbyte, (int)desSize), Response.ContentType);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include some explanation of what this code does, and how this answers the question. A code block by itself is not immediately useful for those who come across the same issue later on, and adding explanation helps to provide a bit more context.